# what is the url endpoint used in The LinkedIn API documentation to create job alerts

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get job alerts in linkedin, but after getting the access token i realise that all the previous endpoint url that will enable me to create job alerts has been depreceated

```
import requests
import json

# Set your LinkedIn API credentials
client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"

# Set the job search criteria
job_title = "Software Engineer"
location = "San Francisco"
company_name = "Google"


# Create the job alert request
url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/job-alerts"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
data = {
    "jobTitle": job_title,
    "location": location,
    "companyName": company_name
}

# Send the request and get the response
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

# Check the response status code
if response.status_code == 200:
    # The job alert was created successfully
    print("Job alert created successfully!")
else:
    # An error occurred
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
```

i got this error message of

```
404
b'{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Resource job-alerts does not exist","status":404}'
```